# PHP- insert todays date into MySql field not working

Tags: php, mysql

Pretty simple to some people, but pretty new to PHP. I just want to insert today date into a date field in MySQL

Thanks in advance.

```
$sql = "UPDATE IA SET IASubmitted ='yes', IASubmittedDate='date('Y-m-d')' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: where is your date value for IASubmittedDate, I can only see a string?

Comment: what is the type of IASubmittedDate in DB, timestamp or date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest answer is as follows:

```
$sql = "UPDATE IA SET IASubmitted ='yes', IASubmittedDate='". date('Y-m-d'). "' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');

sql = "UPDATE IA SET IASubmitted ='yes', IASubmittedDate='". $date. "' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sql = "UPDATE IA SET IASubmitted ='yes', IASubmittedDate='" DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') "' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this without the php `date()` function by using MySQLs `CURDATE()` function. This should look like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE IA SET IASubmitted ='yes', IASubmittedDate=CURDATE() WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

$sql = "UPDATE IA SET IASubmitted ='yes', IASubmittedDate=now() WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

This will work both:
when IASubmittedDate is date or
IASubmittedDate is datetime